# Is this user management system safe?

Tags: cordova, curl, couchdb, phonegap, pouchdb

I am currently doing the user management system for a Cordova/PhoneGap app using PouchDB/CouchDB.

Is this approach acceptable and reasonably secure?

1) **Signup** happens via an Ajax call to an API on my website. (USERNAME and PASSWORD are user input)

```
$.post('https://example.com/api', {
  user: "USERNAME",
  password: "PASSWORD"
}, function(data){
  // Something like "Success" or "Username is taken"
});
```

2) If USERNAME and PASSWORD are acceptable (e.g. username isn't already taken), the API will use cURL to connect to my Cloudant CouchDB instance (with Admin rights) and

a) add the user to the _users database

b) create a database for the user

c) give the user _reader and _writer permissions to his own database

(The following is a code example for 2b)

```
<?php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ACCOUNT.cloudant.com/USERNAME/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $USERINFO); // object containing USERNAME and PASSWORD
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Accept: */*'
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'ADMINUSERNAME:ADMINPASSWORD'); // Admin credentials for my Cloudant instance

$response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

3) Finally, if the client receives a "Success" from the Ajax call, it will log in to CouchDB via the [PouchDB authentication plugin](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication):

```
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('https://ACCOUNT.cloudant.com/USERNAME');

remoteDB.login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD').then(function (response) {
  // "Success"
});
```

For simplicity, I've omitted things like santizing and error handling etc. This question is just about the structure and methods that I'm using :)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don’t know CouchDB, but regarding 2, would it be possible to create an account that can only be used to create new database, but does not have any other rights? That would be a little safer already.

Comment: That's a way to do it. Note, using Couch auth system, you can revoke cookie and it doesn't provide and password recovery and stuff